# Fijar ejes de coordenadas en ggplot2

Tags: r

Resulta que tengo una función escrita en R para imprimir un gráfico box and whisker plot. Lo que hago en cuestión es esto:

```
mytitle2 <- "Contenido = 1.0"
a <-subset(global_data,Contenido==1.0 & Rango==3)
ggplot(d, aes(fase)) +
  labs(title=mytitle2) +
  xlab("fase") +
  ylab("intensidad") +
  geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=.2,height=.1), aes(x=Fase, y=Intensidad, color=Interaccion)) + 
  scale_colour_gradient(low="red", high="blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))
```

Bien. Pues resulta que quiero obtener una serie de gráficos para diferentes valores de "Contenido". El caso es que dados los datos que tengo, algunas veces el eje y aparece con los valores entre 0 y 3, mientras que otras veces (cuando los datapoints se acumulan cerca de 3), el eje x por defecto aparece acortado, representando solo valores entre 1 y 3.

Me gustaría saber cómo fijar los ejes de coordenadas para que los gráficos siempre representen los valores asignados en el rango de 0 a 3.

Gracias.

Comment: Además, resulta que el título de la leyenda queda pegado, casi solapando con los valores de la leyenda. Por lo que también me gustaría incrementar en esta función la distancia entre título de leyenda y leyenda (he intentado manipular leyend.key y leyend.key.size, pero nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veamos que opciones tenemos para configurar los ejes en `ggplot`. En primer lugar generamos un gráfico similar a tu ejemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(100)
mytitle2 <- "Contenido = 1.0"
global_data <- data.frame(Fase = runif(1000, min=0, max=3), 
                          Intensidad = runif(1000, min=0, max=3), 
                          Interaccion=sample(1:5, 1000, replace = TRUE))
a <-subset(global_data,Intensidad > 2 & Fase > 2)
ggplot(a, aes(fase)) +
    labs(title=mytitle2) +
    xlab("fase") +
    ylab("intensidad") +
    geom_point(position=position_jitter(width=.2,height=.1), aes(x=Fase, y=Intensidad, color=Interaccion)) + 
    scale_colour_gradient(low="red", high="blue") +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))
```

En este ejemplo hemos recortada la muestra del eje `x` e `y` a los valores más cercanos a `3`, si vemos el gráfico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vemos que el eje `x` se auto ajustó a la muestra, si no queremos que ocurra esto, hay que repetir lo que has hecho para el eje `y`, es decir:

```
+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 3))
```

o bien para los dos ejes también podemos usar:

```
 + xlim(0, 3)
 + ylim(0, 3)
```

Por otro lado, lo que mencionas de las etiquetas de los ejes puedes resolverlo configurando `axis.title.y` y `axis.title.x` de `theme()`, hay que definir un `element_text` y configurar los `margin` definiendo las propiedades top, rigth, bottom y left.

```
+ theme(axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 30, b = 0, l = 0)),
      axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 30, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)))
```

Para el título de la leyenda de los indicadores de color no he encontrado ninguna opción en la configuración del tema, pero siempre puedes configurara manualmente el título y agregarle un salto de línea, por ejemplo:

```
scale_colour_gradient(name="Title\n", low="red", high="blue") +
```

El resultado final sería algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, excelente respuesta. Añadir que en el código que presenté como ejemplo scale_colour_gradient no estaba funcionando al ser la variable "Interacción" una variable discreta. Por lo tanto, R tampoco llegaba a leer correctamente el límite asignado mediante scale_y_continuous

Comment: Volviendo a la cuestión del etiquetado y su separación. Entiendo que con axis de theme() puedo configurar los márgenes. Es decir apartar o aproximar más los títulos y la leyenda. Pero el problema que tengo es que -en mi gráfico- el título de la propia leyenda (en el ejemplo "Interacción") está solapado literalmente con la propia leyenda. No sé si puedo incrementar la separación entre título de leyenda y barra de colores de la leyenda.

Comment: @pyring, no encontré forma de configurarlo pero siempre puedes agrega un salto de línea al titulo.

Comment: ¡Muy buena solución!